# ViewPager Fragment already added in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have Fragment A with ViewPager which works as I expect. In the bottom of Fragment A, I have one Button that shows A new DialogFragment with A new ViewPager.
when I click on Button and DialogFragment came ups I catch this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added
```

Code In DialogFragment:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mAdapter = new AddNewLeitnerViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    mAdapter.addPage("Title" , new TranslationDialogFragment());
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_new_item_leitner, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    mPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager_add_new_leitner);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return builder.create();
}
```

Codes in ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class AddNewLeitnerViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();

public AddNewLeitnerViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragments.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titles.get(position);
}

public void addPage(String title,Fragment fragment){
    titles.add(title);
    mFragments.add(fragment);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

stack trace :

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: TranslationDialogFragment{224f367} (d95f88ab-18a5-4474-b75d-ffb9e0c1cdfc) id=0x7f09014d android:switcher:2131296589:0}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.addFragment(FragmentStore.java:67)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1563)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:405)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2167)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1990)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1945)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1847)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

what is the problem??

Comment: See #3 in https://proandroiddev.com/the-seven-actually-10-cardinal-sins-of-android-development-491d2f64c8e0

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yeah Fixed that but not working yet!

Comment: You probably shouldn't put a DialogFragment inside a ViewPager. But I'd have to see more of why it fails in the stack trace which is cut off

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Sir, I updated my question with stack trace, may you take a look at there?

Comment: It says that the Fragment you are trying to add at position 0 of the ViewPager with `R.id.*` value `2131296589` (which would be in hexa so `0x7F09014D`) is already added when the ViewPager's FragmentPagerAdapter is trying to add it. Very odd, as you've just created it... are you sure the problem isn't that `TranslationDialogFragment` should not be a `DialogFragment` and instead just regular `Fragment`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce problem solved(Kind of). I should write all code in onCreateView callback not in onCreateDialog callback.